# Python pandas operations

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, group-by, data-manipulation

My Dataframe is like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['absf123', 'absf123', 'absf123', 'sdf123', 'sdf123', 'sdf123', 'sdf123'], 'B': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2], [12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23], [18, 19, 20, 21], [9]]})
```

the results in column "C" should be `No,Yes,No,Yes,No,No,Yes`.

the logic goes like for example: first row should be No because value 2 appears in other values of absf123. I have 4lacs rows.

Here is my code but not getting the desired result

```py
def is_subset_of_others(df):
    grouped=see.groupby('A')
    
    df['C']=False    
    for _,group in grouped:
        
        alpha_positions=[set(row['B']) for _, row in group.iterrows()]
        for i, row in group.iterrows():
            
            is_subset=all(set(row['A']).issubset(set(other)) or set(row['B']) == set(other) for other in alpha_positions if other!= set(row['B']))
            df.loc[i,'C']=is_subset 
    
    #df['result']=results
    
    return df
```